# How to upload a large video file into server path in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have develop a asp.net mvc3 web application, in that i want upload images and videos.Images are save inserver path but when i upload more than 50MB video file it showing error

```
   This webpage is not availableThe webpage at http://localhost:1318/Campaign/Advertises might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this web page later.
Error 101 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET): The connection was reset.
```

This is i got the error please help me how can i resolve this to upload a file in server path .

Comment: You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx). [Silverlight File Upload](http://silverlightfileupld.codeplex.com/) is one component that you could use on the client.

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your web.config file:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="<kilobytes allowed per upload>" />
```

so if you want to allow files up to 50 megs, set this.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" />
```

Comment: Hi thank you for giving respanse.already i have set this MaxRequestlenth in my web.config file.  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="2000" maxRequestLength="10240" />

Comment: Yeah, that should allow you to upload files about 10 megs in size. You'll want to increase that. If you look at Darin's Answer, you can find more in-depth explanations and solutions to your problem.